# Android Development: Undefined Method

Tags: android

Hi I´m new to Android and Eclipse. I have just following the tutorial from developer.android.com. Right now I´m in [adding ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html)

Right now I´m at this part

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have received an error for `openSearch()` and `openSettings()`. It said that The method `openSettings()` is undefined for the type `DisplayMessageActivity`. What shoud I do now?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [openSearch() in Android beginners app not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727033/opensearch-in-android-beginners-app-not-defined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`openSearch()` and `openSettings()` are methods that the author of the tutorial created in order to perform other operations.  Search well into the code, there must be somewhere the declaration of those methods, if the author made them visible.

They should look something like this:

```
public void openSearch() {
    //Do something here.
}

public void openSettings() {
    //Do something here.
}
```

Replacing the `//Do something here` with the code implementation present in the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Im up to the same section as you, they haven't provided the methods but you have to implement them as stated above.

However I found code to open up the device settings using this code in the switch;

```
case R.id.action_settings:
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS));
        return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

define them.

You're basing your code on an incomplete snippet. That snippet makes no expectation of what it means to search or create settings in your app... that's your job to implement. This snippet is only concerned about showing you how to establish the action bar, not the whole application.

Answer (score 2):

The methods openSearch() and openSettings() should be defined. Use the following code. It'd help..

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id){
    case R.id.action_search :
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SEARCH_SETTINGS));
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings :
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS));
        return true;
    default :
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should code those methods?

```
private void  openSearch(){
    //your code here
}

private void openSettings(){
     //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those two methods are just examples how selecting an option can start an action. The implementation was not provided because it was irrelevant to the example. Note that it is *not* a tutorial, but a single and un-compile-able example of how to add behavior to an options item.