# openSearch() in Android beginners app not defined

Tags: android

I'm just started the Android beginners tutotial and I now face a problem. On [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#Respond) under "Respond to Action Buttons" it tells me to define a switch statement with some of the options calling the `openSearch()` and `openSettings()` methods. These methods however, are not defined yet (duh) which thus gives me an error.

The tutorial doesn't say anything however, about how to define them. Can anybody give me a pointer on what and where I should define thess methods? Should they be in the same file, and if so, what should they contain?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

These methods are just examples that Google put in to show how you would use a switch statement. You can put anything you want in there, but I think the point is to make function calls from a switch statement, instead of putting the code of a function in the statement, to keep code clean. The functions would probably be declared in the same .java file in some fashion like

```
private void openSearch() {
    // start or show the search activity/fragment
}
```

They can technically contain anything you want them to, depending on what you want the action bar button to do. If you simply want to see that the buttons work, you can splash a Toast notification to see something appear

```
private void openSearch() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Search button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You'll have to import the Toast package which can be done by `Ctrl+Shift+O`. (Or `Cmd+Shift+O` for Mac)

Hope this helps clear up confusion.

Comment: Thanks drees I'm a beginner too so your comment really helped. I used your suggestion and ADK didn't like DURATION_SHORT and suggested I change it to LENGTH_LONG or LENGTH_SHORT `private void openSettings() { Toast.makeText(this, "Settings button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }` Not sure why. Also had to use ctrl shift O to get the right package. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks @user2835610 for the comment! Turns out I was just going off memory and that Toast.LENGTH_SHORT is the correct syntax. I made the edit

Answer (score 6):

This is the code that you have to use in those methods:

```
private void openSearch(){
    startActivity(new Intent(SearchManager.INTENT_ACTION_GLOBAL_SEARCH));
}

private void openSettings(){
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
}
```

The openSearch() method execute the google global search of the cellphone.
The openSettings() method open the global configuration of the cellphone.

I'm also a beginner in android,hope this helps with the question. Good Luck

Comment: Actually I have found that those methods are created as an example of actions of your app. You don't have to put something in there. The search function have to filter data inside your app and the settings function is supposed to call the settings of your own application. You can use the example that I posted in order to learn about the different actions that interact with your cellphone anyways.

Answer (score 1):

[drees](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2433309/drees) (thanks for Toast) answered the question for the satisfaction of the beginning android programmer (which I am), but to actually answer the question asked, you need to follow the instructions in the **Setting Up The Search Interface** [article](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html), however you need to preemptively understand how to place the commented material here into the switch statement's openSearch() method.

I guess the *real* question is, though: Why does the android tutorial use this methodology instead of having a nonlinear explanation to add real content as the situation requires OR at least link to it to follow it out OR at least let you know that you're going to be obtain an end product that is at best broken code.