# New to android studio and java, stuck with an error I can't fix

Tags: java, android

I am working with [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html), and I got stuck.

I get an error on `openSettings();` and `openSearch();` the program says

> can not resolve method

Could anyone please tell me what have I done wrong?

```
@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        openSetting();
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_search) {
        openSearch();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Please post your complete code of the class + the logcat of the Exception

Comment: possible duplicate of [openSearch() in Android beginners app not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727033/opensearch-in-android-beginners-app-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess I think you are following example from here:
https://github.com/arun-gupta/android-samples/blob/master/HelloWorldProject/HelloWorld/src/main/java/name/arungupta/android/helloworld/MainActivity.java

To solve your problem you need to a add these two methods in your class:

```
    private void openSettings() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(SETTINGS_MESSAGE, "Settings");
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void openSearch() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(SEARCH_MESSAGE, "Search Now");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: It means that I need to open new activities for Search and Setting now right?

Comment: Yes, you need these classes defined as well.  Those activities will called only if a user click on those Options. Link in my response has those classes defined